# springmvc using json response error

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have the following controller in springmvc.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "main";
    }
}
```

getting following error when i request to `http://localhost:8080/Woodcutter/` url

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods `home(String)` and `external_page(String)` in `HomeController` mapped to the same url `http://localhost:8080/Woodcutter/`. You can map only one method mapped to a particular URL with HTTP method (GET / POST), That's the ambiguity. Please change the URL for one of the method or remove one. How can a request be delegated to two methods matching the URL and HTTP method? Think.

Answer (score 0):

This is because two method pointing to same URL so your controller confused.You cant have two url path same than ambiguous problem will accrues.